# Traveler Guitar string loudness

Tags: guitar

I just purchased the traveler guitar acoustic/electric.  There are videos online showing people playing this guitar without an amp and getting descent loudness.  However when I try, I can barely hear anything.

Are there certain types of strings that play louder than others?  I realize This guitar is not hollow body so it won't sound that loud but I would like to be able to like to hear it a little bit so I can practice without an amp.

Comment: What model traveler guitar do you have?  Can you link an example video?

Comment: Here ya go...  http://www.musiciansfriend.com/guitars/traveler-guitar-ultra-light-acoustic-electric-travel-guitar

Comment: You are supposed to use headphones

Comment: This video makes me believe otherwise...  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=KgMVBvIw0K0

Comment: The guitar you've linked is a solid body with a built in piezo pickup. It won't produce much sound at all, unless amplified or using a built in preamplifier. So I'm sorry, the sound in any advertising videos you've seen has been added after filming. If you no longer want the guitar you might want to ask the sellers about a return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I own a Traveler too, although a different model, but no, different strings won't do what you need. Not sure how that video was produced, but any electric guitar will need an amp for any sort of amplitude.

While product suggestions are off-topic in this forum, you may want to consider a headphone amp or similar. When I travel, I use a Vox headphone amp - I'd imagine there's other makes out there.